# 'read binary' on files vs. 'join' on strings in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, join, binary

I'm re-writing an older script which generates a lot of temporary files for saving and exchanging information/data between functions. I want to keep them  as variables, to avoid the overhead of generating files.

My problem: I encountered a function in which two files are merged on a binary level using this code:

```
with open(first_file, "ab") as file1, open(second_file, "rb") as file2: 
        file1.write(file2.read())
```

I would like to do the same, using strings and the '.join' function like this:

```
first_file = ''.join([first_file, second_file])
```

My question: is the .join function equivalent to 'read binary'? Or does the 'read binary' mode even apply to .join?

The data I'm working on is binary, so the simple 'read' command would potentially alter the contents.

So far I found this info in the official Python documentation:

> Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files;
>   the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered
>   slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes
>   modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll
>   corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files.

Comment: Why not trying the code and seeing if the result is the same in both cases?

Comment: Because I haven't finished with the whole rework yet and it would require many work-arounds to get this functionality working. Also I hoped for some theoretical background, to undestand the functions better. So far I haven't found any infos regarding my question on the internet.

Comment: You only need a stub, make two files "a.txt" and "b.txt", write something in both, run the lines you posted on the files and see if the results match

Answer (score 0):

Making a small test:
`a.txt` contains `'Hello'`, 'b.txt' contains `'World'`.

```python
with open('a.txt', "ab") as file1, open('b.txt', "rb") as file2: 
  file1.write(file2.read())
```

Now `a.txt` contains `'HelloWorld'`.

Checking with the other snippet, after changing back `a.txt` to "Hello":

```python
with open('a.txt', "rb") as file1, open('b.txt', "rb") as file2: 
  first_file = file1.read()
  second_file = file2.read()

first_file = b''.join([first_file, second_file]) 
with open('a.txt', 'wb') as fp:
  fp.write(first_file)
```

Now the content of `a.txt` is again `'HelloWorld'`, so the two methods are equivalent (with respect to the result at least).
Obviously, though, the first method is more compact.

Comment: Well, that's not false, but IMHO `first_file += second_file` is more compact is simpler to understand...

Comment: From the official Python documentation: "Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files." That's why I'm asking - the data in 'my' files is binary and not text.

Comment: @SergeBallesta indeed, but the OP's question was specific between these two methods.

Comment: @redscale from that quote (which would go very well in your question, btw), I understand that reading binary fils as text, concatenating that, and writing it back is a bad idea. What I'm doing is reading bytes, without decoding them. So, there is no newline alteration

Answer (score 0):

Read-binary is somewhat similar to using r"somestring" to indicate raw strings - the underlying file *is* binary, you're just telling Python to **skip** trying to decode the binary data into ASCII or UTF-8 or what-have-you characters.

So, the mode doesn't really apply here.

Since join operates on strings, you'd need to **open file A**, **read** it as a string, then **do the same for B**, whereas the original code just needs to read B and seek to the end of file A to start writing. So, you're not really getting much mileage out of doing a str.join, and you're actually using *more* memory.

If you want to optimize, make a loop that reads B line by line with writes it - that allows you to load just one line's worth of memory at a time rather than dumping the whole B file into it all at once.

Comment: As it happens, this runs exactly in the error the quote from Python docs warns you from. If you read a binary file as a string (**i.e., `open('a.txt', 'r')`**), the line-breaks **will** get corrupted. Using `rb` prevents exactly that,since the result of `fp.read()` with a binary file is a `bytestring` (which in python 2.7 is a regular string).

Comment: Also, `r'somestring'` does **not** indicate that the underlying is "binary". It simpy states that the characters should be taken literally and not escaped (e.g., `'\n'` will be a new line and have `len('\n') == 1` but `r'\n'` is the two separate characters and you'll have `len(r'\n') == 2`)

Comment: Re 1: of course they will, a newline is a character too. You don't need a line-break to iterate over the file though, you can read and write it a byte at a time, or any other arbitary chunk of data. Newlines are just a convenient convention provided by textual data.

Comment: Yes, unless you're using binary data. In that case, as the quote in the question explains, "the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written". If a binary file happens to have somewhere some bytes that encode a newline, those bytes will be changed and this will break your binary file. That's why opening in binary mode is the way to go here

Comment: Re 2: I'm... not sure why you've made an assumption I'm saying they do that? I was making an analogy, not saying they are the same thing.

Comment: I'm not making assumptions, I'm just saying that your analogy is confusing because there is no decoding to ASCII or UTF-8 for r'strings' or normal strings. The only difference between them is how escaped characters are interpreted, which has nothing to do with the difference between opening a file in binary or text mode

Comment: I see what happened now, there was an edit I missed. Still, I don't see why are we even arguing here - I'm not saying you shouldn't use 'rb', just that it's not relevant to str.join. As for the analogy being confusing - fair enough.